# Which shell will execute the cmd when popen is called

Tags: unix, ansi-c

First of all, forgive my awful english.....

This is the prototype

```
FILE *popen(const char* cmd_string, const char* type);
```

Here is my question, the book says that when popen function is called, it will call exec to get a shell to execute the cmd_string we give to popen, but I'm not sure which shell will exec get, so can anyone give me an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try and see:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  FILE *fp;
  char var[5];

  fp = popen("echo $0", "r");
  fgets(var, 5, fp);
  printf("%s", var);
}
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ./a.out
sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood now, it's really helpful, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

/bin/sh : From the doc:

```
   The command argument is a pointer to a null-terminated string
   containing a shell command line.  This command is passed to /bin/sh
   using the -c flag; interpretation, if any, is performed by the shell.
```